# I'm new to flutter and I want to add another text, How can I do it?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFb4c8ea),
      ),
      home: const MyText(),
    );
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyText({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "RAYCAN",
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xFF69418b),
            height: -2,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 58,
            letterSpacing: 2,
            wordSpacing: 1,
            fontFamily: "LilitaOne",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried many things and didn't seem to work, maybe I should change something but I don't know what I'm doing. How should I do it? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Text directly you can use column or row widget like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child:Column(
    children:[
      Text(
      "RAYCAN",
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: const Color(0xFF69418b),
        height: -2,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 58,
        letterSpacing: 2,
        wordSpacing: 1,
        fontFamily: "LilitaOne",
      ),
    ),
     Text(
      "RAYCAN",
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: const Color(0xFF69418b),
        height: -2,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 58,
        letterSpacing: 2,
        wordSpacing: 1,
        fontFamily: "LilitaOne",
      ),
    ),
  
 ],)
  ),
);
```

it will display the text widget one after another in column wise and if you want to display it in the row just replace the

> Column

with

> Row

in above code

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple Text widget or any other widget we need to use widget that supports multi widget or children. Those are could be `Column` , `Row` , `Listview` etc.

Checkout this documentation for more details,

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout